# How to convert a string of numbers from an input into an array/vector?

Tags: matlab

Inputting a number, e.g.

```
StudentNo = input('Please input your student number: ')
```

so that

```
StudentNo = 54456842
```

Putting this in and then making it into individual numbers

```
StudentNo = [5,4,4,5,6,8,4,2]
```

in order to find the avg or other stats from the digits without getting NaN?

Comment: Will the Student number always be a single digit or will it vary?

Answer (score 3):

You can break it up into digits with the following approach

```
str2num(num2str(StudentNo).')
```

This first converts `StudentNo` to a string, then takes the transpose such that each character is on it's own line, and then we call `str2num` to convert each row to a separate number.

Another option would be to convert to a string and then subtract off the ASCII value of `'0'` to convert each character to a numeric digit

```
num2str(StudentNo) - '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Input captures a single number. It would be hard to know how many digits each of the student numbers is so I would suggest getting them one by one:

```
StudentNo = input('Please input your student number one by one (end with -1): ');
while StudentNo(end)~= -1
    StudentNo = [StudentNo, input('Please input the next student number (end with -1): ')];
end
% remove the -1
StudentNo = StudentNo(1:end-1);
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on @StewieGriffin: comment if you have multi-digit student number you could just do this:

```
StudentNo = input('Please input the next student number: ')];
[1 2 12 13]
```

This will detect each number as separate entry in a vector of your student numbers.

Comment: Suever's approach handles the variable number of digits quite nicely, so I don't think that's a big issue. If however, you really want to input one by one, it would probably be easier to just input them all inside brackets: `[1 2 3 4]`, thus avoiding the while loop.

Comment: The problem is with multi-digit student numbers, as in: `[1 2 12 45]` which would be converted into `[1 2 1 2 4 5]`. I did not know that `input` can actually detect `[]` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Suever's approach is a neat way to do this. However, if you don't need the actual number as a number, and you only need the separate digits, then you can specify directly that you want the numbers as a string in the `input`-call.

```
StudentNo = input('Please input student number: ', 's')
```

Here, the `'s'` specifies that the input is a string. This way you can input the `StudentNo` without having apostrophes.

```
StudentNo = input('Please input student number: ', 's')
Please input student number: 54456842
StudentNo =
54456842
```

You can now use any of the two approaches in Suever's answer to convert this to separate numbers. Another option is to simply do the subtraction by `'0'` in the call itself:

```
StudentNo = input('Please input student number: ', 's')-'0'
Please input student number: 54456842
StudentNo =
     5     4     4     5     6     8     4     2
```

Since this is a bit hard to read, you can also have this as an anonymous function:

```
stid = @() input('Please input student number: ', 's')-'0';
```

And call it like this:

```
stid()
Please input student number: 123456
ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     6
```